# File on HDFS used for initializing objects in Flink job

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink

I have this weird problem with Flink: in a job I have to initialize an object with pre-compiled resource files. And after the job starts, it runs without problem in the first time. But when I access it again with web interface exactly like the first time, my object can't get initialized and the error is:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: hdfs:/.../.../my_file

which confuses me because the file is there and the object gets initialized successfully the first time. The related code is:

```
Config.load(Files.newBufferedReader(
    Paths.get("hdfs:///xx/xx/myconfig.cfg"),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I don't get any problem if the resources are on local system and I run a local server with the same job. So does anyone have any clue?

edit: full trace

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: hdfs:/path/to/xx.cfg
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
at myObject(myObject.java:364)
at myclass$mymethod.map(myclass.java:126)
at myclass$mymethod.map(myclass.java:1)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:35)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OutputHandler$CopyingOperatorCollector.collect(OutputHandler.java:272)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?
What do you exactly mean with "But when I access it again with web interface exactly like the first time" .. are you talking about Flink's JobManager interface (on 8081) or about the web client (8080) ?

Comment: thank you for the comment, I meant I have a web application that access the job, and use it to process data and display result on the web. full stack trace see the edited post.

Comment: I'm not sure if this problem is really related to Flink.
From the Exception, it seems that the BufferedReader is trying to access the file from the local file system, not from HDFS.
Maybe the `hdfs://` handler registration at the JVM is not working as expected? Have you tried using the regular HDFS APIs?
How did you integrate the web server into your Flink job?